# Display images in loop and add label depending on the picture

Tags: python, loops, imshow

I have a list of numpy arrays corresponding to pictures. I want to label these pictures. To do so I created a loop inside which I show every picture and ask for the label using the `input()` function.

The issue is that the window only shows the picture after I entered the label.

The following code reproduces my issue:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [np.random.rand(32,22), np.random.rand(32,32)]

for i in range(len(data)):
    plt.imshow(data[i])
    plt.show()
    label = input('Enter label\n')
```

Comment: it working fine in jupyter notebook and spyder

Comment: @SayedSohan and of course I'm using Pyzo. I'll use one of these then thanks!